# i have navigation using routing. every time when i go to other page and come back i lose all values of variables . how can i fix this?

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, routes, components

for example:
i have component users and array "userInfo" in it. i push some info in the "userInfo". then when i go to another component (using routerLink) and then back to users component "userInfo" array is empty.

here: every time i navigate to another page an back cartItems array becomes empty

```
export class CartComponent implements OnInit {
  cartItems:Item[] = [];
  quantity:number = 1;
  constructor(private cartDataService:CartDataService) { }

  up(){
    this.quantity++;
  }
  down(){
    if(this.quantity>1){
      this.quantity--;
    }
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.cartDataService.myCartData$
    .subscribe(
      cartData => {
        this.cartItems.push(cartData)
    

      }
    )
  }
```

Comment: i tried. to subscribe cartData as array and then concat but i got the same result

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a state management tool that helps you preserve global data in your application.

Personally, I recommend NgRx [1]

[1] https://ngrx.io/docs

Comment: I would recommend to start small, with a shared service (probably provided in root) rather than jumping into complex state management solutions like ngrx :).

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu that's for sure 